# Trigger Property to restart storyboard to first state

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, storyboard, wpf-animation

I have 2 Trigger events, both with an `<Trigger.EnterActions>` and a `<Trigger.ExitActions>` and these are `IsPressed` and also `IsMouseOver`.

When I click on a button it will play `<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">` storyboard:

```
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
   <Trigger.EnterActions>
       <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseDownTimeLine}"/>
   </Trigger.EnterActions>
   <Trigger.ExitActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseUpTimeLine}"/>
   </Trigger.ExitActions>
 </Trigger>
```

and this is linked to this storyboard:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="MouseDownTimeLine" >
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Pressed" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" >
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="1" />
     </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Key="MouseUpTimeLine">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Pressed" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" >
        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.25" Value="1"/>
     </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

A different button is also linked to the same Storyboard. When the second button is clicked I want it to play the storyboard as it does, but then for the first button to go back to the normal state. Which is this part of the Storyboard.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="MouseExitTimeLine">
     <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Normal" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" >
          <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.00" Value="1"/>
     </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

      <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="Hover" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" >
           <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.00" Value="0"/>
       </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

**When the second button is clicked how do I trigger the first button to reset to Normal**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong here, but it seems like you have radio button functionality baked into button template. When you click a button it stays "clicked" (or checked) and when you click another button it "releases" the click from first button.

I'd change the target type of the template to `RadioButton` and the trigger to:

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
   <Trigger.EnterActions>
       <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ButtonCheckedStoryboardBegin"
                        Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseDownTimeLine}"/>
   </Trigger.EnterActions>
   <Trigger.ExitActions>
       <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ButtonCheckedStoryboardBegin"/>
   </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>
```

Using `StopStoryboard` because duratios in MouseExitTimeLine are zero. If you actually need duration for exit animation, use:

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
   <Trigger.EnterActions>
       <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseDownTimeLine}"/>
   </Trigger.EnterActions>
   <Trigger.ExitActions>
       <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseExitTimeLine}"/>
   </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>
```

[second option can be used as is - with zero duration, but it's less elegant, IMO]

Also, the animation for "Hover" in MouseExitTimeLine is redundant and can be removed since MouseDownTimeLine is not setting anything on "Hover".

Now, on each instance of `RadioButton` in layout, add `GroupName="<Some string here>"`. Only one radio button in a group can be checked at any given point in time.

Comment: When i change the Template to RadioButton I get massive errors. `RadioButton ControlTemplate TargetType does not match templated type Button` ?

Comment: You need to change instances of `Button` to `RadioButton`.